# Prove or disprove a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ satisfying $ |f(x)-f(y)| \geq \log (1+|x-y|), \text {for all } x, y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that:
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \geq \log (1+|x-y|), \text { for all } x, y \in \mathbb{R} \text {. }
$$

I need to know about the surjectivity of $f$. By fixing $y$, I got $|f(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, but how to finalize? Any counters for bijection (already it is injection from the condition)?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: $x \neq y$ implies $\ln(1+|x-y|)>0$, which says $f(x) \neq f(y)$. In this way, I have the injectivity. But I need to know whether it is bijection or need not be.

Comment: If a $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  is continuous and surjective, it must be monotone.

Comment: I think you mean continuous and injective then monotone, right? But how it leads to injectivity

Comment: WLOG we can assume that $f$ is increasing. If $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=M<+\infty$, then try to find a contradiction; similarly you can prove that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. The intermediate property now implies that $f$ is surjective. You can add some more attempts into your question using the hints in these comments to prevent this interesting question from being closed. (I haven't voted to close.)

Comment: Or you can [answer your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), now that the hints gave you a complete solution.